# How do I implement shared functionality across methods for diagnostic purposes in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 3.1 app. In this app, I have the following boilerplate methods:

```
public List<Item> GetAll()
{
    // retrieve all items from the database
}

public async Task<List<Item>> GetAllAsync()
{
    // retrieve all items from the database
}

public List<Item> GetAll(bool includeDeleted, DateTime? after)
{
  // retrieve all items based on the query details passed in as parameters.
}

public Item Get(int id)
{
    // retrieve a specific item from the database
}

public async Task<Item> GetAsync(int id)
{
    // retrieve a specific item from the database.
    // The id parameter is needed
}

public void DoSomething()
{
  // No parameters are needed
}
```

In these methods, and other methods in my project, I have a *lot* of boilerplate code. That boilerplate code basically 1) logs performance and 2) provides generic error handling.At this time, the boilerplate stuff basically looks like this:

```
var log = new Log("<Friendly Method Name Goes Here">);

Stopwatch stopwatch = null;
try 
{
  stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    
  // method code
  log.Result = null, Item, or List<Item> depending on which method is called

  stopwatch.Stop();
  log.ElapsedTicks = stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
  log.Success = true;
}
catch (Exception) 
{
  log.Success = false;
}
```

Instead of copying the above and putting it into every method, it seems like I should be able to pass in the "real work" that needs to be done into one method and populate something like a `Result` object that includes the real result and the metadata (i.e. performance, friendly method name, etc.) This lead me down the path of putting something like the following into each method:

```
var result = new Result();
Func<Task> task = async (result) =>
{
  var outcome = // get item(s) from database
  result.Result = outcome;
  await Task.CompletedTask;
};
```

I was then going to put my boilerplate code into a shared method and pass in `task`. However, quickly ran into some problems:

1. How do I pass in zero, one, or more parameters?
2. I can write metadata on the `Result` object in the `Func`. However, how do I update properties on the `Result` object in the in the shared method (the thing that logs performance, etc.)?

I can't tell if I'm overlooking something in C# or if I have an architectural problem. I feel like having shared code that handles core things (i.e. measure performance), yet flexible enough to customize at a more granular level is reasonable. Is there a way to do this in C#? If so, how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it, it's not the most efficient way but it's pretty simple. Your parameters that you use become closures in the boilerplate context, no need to worry about that unless you're doing some heavy lifting in memory. First class defines the boilerplate operations, you get name of the method and source file that calls you for logging purposes automatically. Second class implements the boilerplate context. Supports sync and async overloads, you may need to add 2 more overloads without return types for void methods but that's easy. You can expand the Func<> definition with more types and pass something from the boilerplate to methods like DB context factory or something.

```
namespace Test
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    public static class Boilerplate
    {
        // Boilerplater (tm) for async methods
        public static async Task<T> Run<T>(Func<Task<T>> operation, [CallerMemberName] string method = null, [CallerFilePath] string module = null)
        {
            // some boilerplate init
            Console.WriteLine($"Method {method} started.");

            var result = await operation.Invoke();

            // some wrapup
            Console.WriteLine($"Method {method} ended.");

            return result;
        }

        // Boilerplater (tm) for sync methods
        public static T Run<T>(Func<T> operation, [CallerMemberName] string method = null, [CallerFilePath] string module = null)
        {
            // some boilerplate init
            Console.WriteLine($"Method {method} started.");

            var result = operation.Invoke();

            // some wrapup
            Console.WriteLine($"Method {method} ended.");

            return result;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Example app
    /// </summary>
    public class MyApp
    {
        public async Task<List<string>> GetAllAsync(string input) 
            => await Boilerplate.Run(async () =>
            {
                // do something async in the boilerplate context
                var result = new List<string>();
                await Task.Delay(1);
                result.Add(input);
                return result;
            });

        public List<string> GetAll(string input) 
            => Boilerplate.Run(() =>
            {
                // do something non-async in the boilerplate context
                var result = new List<string>();
                result.Add(input);
                return result;
            });
    }
}
```

And of course this has no error handling, it would just be too long to post, just a proof of concept.